# Mocking connection pool and test url param using sinon?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am doing a RESTful api using node.js,

Unit Testing using mocha, sinon, chai.

DB using ibm DB2.

**Problem**:

I am trying to a unit test on the getNews method.

I know the correct way of doing a unit test is not to access the database. So I am trying not to access the database.

**Q1:**
However, how do I do a mock on `pool.open(connString, function (err, db)` to return a fake result, assuming that I created the json result.

Assuming that my newsId that I want to get is 999.

**Q2:**
How do it ensure that the newsId i passed in is 999 and not another value?

**Codes:**

These are files that are already running correctly.

newsRest.js:

```
module.exports = (app) => {

    const controller = require('../controller/newsController');

    app.route('news/:newsId').get(controller.getNews);

};
```

newsController.js:

```
'use strict';

//imports
var connectionString = require('../common/ibmdb2Pool').connectionString;
var connString = connectionString();

var initPool = require('../common/ibmdb2Pool').initPool;
var pool = initPool();

const query = require('../db/query');

/*
 * Restful API starts here
 * */

//get news by id

exports.getNews = (req, res) => {   

    //get from request
    const newsId = req.params.newsId;
    const params = [newsId];

    pool.open(connString, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        db.query(query.sqlSelect, params, function (error, result, info) {

            if (error) {
                console.log(error); 
                return false;
            }

            res.status(200).json({
                result: result
            });
        });
    });
};
```

ibmdb2Pool.js

```
'use strict';

//imports
require('dotenv').config();

var Pool = require("ibm_db").Pool;

// access the environment variables for this environment
var connString = process.env.CONNSTRING;

//variables
const minPoolSize = 20;
const maxPoolSize = 100;

//return connection string from environment file.
exports.connectionString = function () {
    return connString;
};

//init the db pool with a min and max size
exports.initPool = function () {
    var pool = new Pool();

    var ret = pool.init(minPoolSize, connString);

    if(ret !== true) {

        console.log("Cannot init pool. " + ret);
    }

    pool.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);

    return pool;
};
```

Here is my Unit Test class:

newsController.spec.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

var initPool = require('../common/ibmdb2Pool').initPool;
var pool = initPool();

const sinon = require('sinon');
const request = require('request');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const should = chai.should();
let server = require('../../../main.js');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('news service', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            this.open = sinon.stub(pool, 'open');

            });
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            pool.open.restore();
        });

        it('should list a SINGLE news /news/newsId GET', (done) => {

            chai.request(server) 
                .get('/news/999')
                .end(function(err, res){
                    res.should.have.status(200);
                    res.should.be.json;
                    res.body.should.be.a('object');                                 
                    res.body.result.should.include.keys(
                            'NEWS_ID', 'TITLE', 'NEWS_TYPE', 'DESCRIPTION', 'CREATED_BY', 'CREATED_DATE'
                          );
                   done();
               })
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `callsArgWith` :

```
sinon.mock(pool, 'open').callsArgWith(
  1, // argument position
  null, // 1st callback argument
  { success: true } // 2d cb argument
);
```

Details in the sinon [stub documentation](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/)

Comment: how do i go about asserting the values for  `const newsId = req.params.newsId;
    const params = [newsId];`

Comment: oh, wait, what you want is to execute your DB query with a mocked db ?

Comment: Kind of. but db2 has not mock db libraries available. What i wan to do is to mock the db so that it returns me a dummy results.